# Bundle is getting null and it didn't take the bundle args

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

Im developing a small android application, i was using shared preference in order to transfer data between fragments. now i want to use bundle but the problem is the bundle in the second fragment getting null value how do i solve that problem ?
here are some part of code

```
... some usefull Code  in first fragment


args.putLong("favoriteCountry", countryListSpinnerData.get(favoriteCountrySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getId());
                args.putInt("favoriteCurrency", currencySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                args.putDouble("favoriteBudget", Double.parseDouble(budgetEditText.getText().toString()));
                args.putString("additionalInformation", additionalInformationEditText.getText().toString());
                MoneyPartnerShipStepTwo moneyPartnerShipStepTwo = new MoneyPartnerShipStepTwo();
                moneyPartnerShipStepTwo.setArguments(args);
                FragmentHelper.NAVIGATE_FRAGMENT(new MoneyPartnerShipStepTwo(), getActivity())
```

Now the second fragment

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // savedInstanceState is null why ???
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.bundle = savedInstanceState;
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
```

Comment: The bundle that you pass as an argument from `Fragment 1` to `Fragment 2` doesn't arrive in `savedInstanceState` of `Fragment 2`, it's retrievable through for example `getArguments().getInt("YOUR_KEY")`.

Comment: it didn't get pass either way

Answer (score 0):

you create new MoneyPartnerShipStepTwo(), not instance with your argument.
so, please change `FragmentHelper.NAVIGATE_FRAGMENT(moneyPartnerShipStepTwo, getActivity())`

Comment: that is weird how do i forget that i will check it today and i will tell you what is happening